# The data-onsuccess function is not called when using Google-Sign in Javascript

Tags: google-signin

I want the user to be able to sign in with his Google account in his web browser. However, the data-onsuccess method isn't being called.

I uploaded a .html file with the sign in code to my webspace, created a Google API project with the relevant settings. I can see see login button. I can click it and input my Google account data and allow my application to access my account. However, the  data-onsuccess method isn't called and so I cannot react to the successful login.

I tried the login with the [umodified example code](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) from Google and my own code where I added some debugging to see if JS is working at all:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
        <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="CORRECT_VALUE_HERE.apps.googleusercontent.com">
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
        <title>Google sign in test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Google sign in test</h1>
        <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
        <br>
        <a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>
        <br>
        <a href="index.html">Back</a>
        <br>
        <a href="#" onclick="someTest()">JavaScript Test</a>
        <br>
        <ul>
            <li id="gID">Google ID, temporary</li>
            <li id="gFullName">Full Name</li>
            <li id="gGivenName">Given Name</li>
            <li id="gFamilyName">FamilyName</li>
            <li id="gImg">Image URL</li>
            <li id="gEMail">E-Mail</li>
            <li id="gToken">Google Token, permanent</li>
        </ul>
        <script>
            function onSignIn(googleUser) {
                alert('in onSignIn');
                // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
                var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
                document.getElementById('gID').textContent = profile.getId();
                document.getElementById('gFullName').textContent = profile.getName();
                document.getElementById('gGivenName').textContent = profile.getGivenName();
                document.getElementById('gFamilyName').textContent = profile.getFamilyName();
                document.getElementById('gImg').textContent = profile.getImageUrl();
                document.getElementById('gEMail').textContent = profile.getEmail();

                // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
                var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
                document.getElementById('gToken').textContent = id_token;
            };
            function someTest() {
                alert('js is working');
                var x = {};
                x.getBasicProfile = function() {
                    var y = {};

                    y.getId = function() { return 'fake id'; };
                    y.getName = function() { return 'fake fake full name'; };
                    y.getGivenName = function() { return 'fake fake given name'; };
                    y.getFamilyName = function() { return 'fake fake family name'; };
                    y.getImageUrl = function() { return 'fake image'; };
                    y.getEmail = function() { return 'fake e-mail'; };

                    return y;
                };

                x.getAuthResponse = function() {
                    var z = {}

                    z.id_token = 'fake id token';

                    return z;
                };

                onSignIn(x);

            };
            function signOut() {
                var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
                auth2.signOut().then(function () {
                    console.log('User signed out.');
                });
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't see any error messages in my browser or my http server. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Things I already tried/checked:

- I check that my client_id in the meta-tag is correct, several times.
- I am sure I set the correct "Authorized JavaScript origin". Otherwise I would see and error message during the loging screen.
- I am sure I am using a correct login. I can can see my example application among the authorized sites in my google account settings.
- I tried moving the script-tag above the div-tags. It doesn't matter. I made sure onSignIn() is a top level JS function.
- I tried hosting this .html file somewhere else (in case Heroku blocks this process somehow). It didn't help.
- I tried this in up to date Firefox and Chrome on Linux and Windows. No difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem: The whole processs does not work when the user has 3rd party cookies disabled in his browser.

Comment: The same goes for browser based signing with Facebook as well.

Comment: @HASSeering My 3rd party cookie is enable yet it still doesnt work